# bash + how to verify folders under specific path are ended with number/s

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, perl

I want to check the folder/s under `/var/kafka` that all them are ended with number otherwhile I will exit with error

```
ls -ltr  /var/kafka
drwxr-xr-x 399 kafka kafka 28672 Nov  9 13:10 data6
drwxr-xr-x 392 kafka kafka 28672 Nov  9 13:10 data5
drwxr-xr-x 391 kafka kafka 28672 Nov  9 13:10 data1
drwxr-xr-x 405 kafka kafka 28672 Nov  9 13:10 data2
drwxr-xr-x 386 kafka kafka 28672 Nov  9 13:10 data4
drwxr-xr-x 389 kafka kafka 28672 Nov  9 13:10 data8
drwxr-xr-x 406 kafka kafka 28672 Nov  9 13:10 data7
drwxr-xr-x 397 kafka kafka 28672 Nov  9 13:10 data3
```

so I create the following simple code ( that should be in bash script )

```
for i in `  ls -ltr  /var/kafka | awk '{print $NF}' `; do  [[ ! $i  = *?[0-9] ]] && echo "ERROR folder/s not ended with number" && exit 1 ; done
```

but this above example is too long code , and I want to find other elegant short command that simply verify if folder/s under `/var/kafka` are ended with number or not,

we can use `awk/sed/` or `Perl` on liner also.

Comment: "but this above example is too long code"
This is your only issue?

Comment: yes I want some simple elegant cli that verify if all folder are ended with number/s

Comment: Consider doing the opposite. Instead of checking if all folders have numbers, look for folders that *do not* have a number at the end

Comment: yes this could be also good option if the cli is simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
files=( /var/kafka/*[^0-9](ND) )
if (( $#files )); then
  print -rlu2 -- "There are files whose name doesn't end in an ASCII digit:" ' - '$^files
  exit 1
fi
```

Same with `bash`:

```
shopt -s nullglob dotglob
shopt -u failglob
files=( /var/kafka/*[^0123456789] )
if (( ${#files[@]} )); then
  echo>&2 "There are files whose name doesn't end in an ASCII digit:"
  printf>&2 ' - %s\n' "${files[@]}"
  exit 1
fi
```

To show only the basename / `t`ail of those files (`foo` instead of `/var/kafka/foo`), replace `$^files` with `$^files:t` and `"${files[@]}"` with `"${files[@]##*/}"`.

Note that strictly speaking `*[^0-9]` (or `*[^0123456789]` in bash) matches on file names that end in a character other than a digit, for file names that don't end with a digit, that's `^*[0-9]` in zsh (for which you need `set -o extendedglob` or `!(*[0-9])` in bash (for which you need `shopt -s extglob`) but given that a file name cannot be empty, that should be equivalent.

If you don't need to list those files in the error message, in zsh, that can be shortened to:

```
if () (( $# )) /var/kafka/*[^0-9](NDY1); then
  print -ru2 "There are files whose name doesn't end in an ASCII digit"
  exit 1
fi
```

Where `Y1` stops looking at the first match, and the list of matches is passed to an anonymous function that returns true if passed at least one argument (`$#` is not zero).

If you need to consider only the files of type *directory*, still in zsh, add `/` to the glob qualifier:

```
dirs=( /var/kafka/*[^0-9](ND/) )
if (( $#dirs )); then
  print -rlu2 -- "There are directories whose name doesn't end in an ASCII digit:" ' - '$^dirs
  exit 1
fi
```

bash doesn't have glob qualifiers, but you could resort to `find` to report the files of type directory whose name doesn't end in digits:

With bash4.4 or newer and a `find` that supports `-print0`:

```
readarray -td '' dirs < <(
  cd /var/kafka &&
    LC_ALL=C find . ! -name . -prune -type d ! -name '*[0-9]' -print0
)
if (( ${#dirs[@]} )); then
  echo>&2 "There are dirs whose name doesn't end in an ASCII digit:"
  printf>&2 ' - %s\n' "${dirs[@]}"
  exit 1
fi
```

With older versions of bash, you can always fill up the array in a loop:

```
dirs=()
while IFS= read -rd '' dir; do
  dirs=("${dirs[@]}" "$dir")
done < <(
  cd /var/kafka &&
    LC_ALL=C find . ! -name . -prune -type d ! -name '*[0-9]' -print0
)
```

We use `LC_ALL=C` so `[0-9]` only matches on the 0123456789 and not the thousands of other characters that often happen to sort between 0 and 9 in other locales, and also so that the `*` in `*[0-9]` which matches on 0 or more characters match on 0 or more bytes instead.

Now beware that some locales use a character encoding where some additional characters, other than 0123456789 have and encoding that end in the same byte value as 0123456789. For instance in the GB18030 charset as used in China:

```
$ LC_ALL=zh_CN.gb18030 luit
$ locale charmap
GB18030
$ printf %s '¾' | LC_ALL=C od -tx1 -tc
0000000  81  30  86  36
        201   0 206   6
0000004
```

The `¾` character is often matched by `[0-9]` regardless of how it's encoded because it sorts between 0 and 9 for obvious reasons, but also, its GB18030 encoding ends in byte 0x36 which happens to also be the encoding of the `6` ASCII digit character.

So in the C locale, the file path that is made of the GB18030 encoding of `/var/kafka/¾¾¾` will be considered to end in an ASCII digit and won't be reported. Whether it should or not is another matter.

Comment: its not works at bash version - GNU bash, version 4.2.46

Comment: If OP only needed a success status, `find` alone could be used e.g.  `find .  ! -name . -prune -type d ! -name '*[0-9]' -exec false {} +` would, afaik, be portable and always exit non-zero if at least one non-match is found.

Answer (score 1):

Using `find`:

```
LC_ALL=C find /var/kafka -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '.*[^0-9]$' | grep '^' \
&& echo "Error in folder name"
```

I'm "abusing" `grep` to get a sensible return code, if someone knows of a better way, please let me know.

Comment: Beware `-regex '.*[^0-9]$'` may fail to match file names that are not valid text in the user's locale (try after `mkdir $'/var/kafka/St\351phane'` in a UTF-8 locale for instance). Using `LC_ALL=C` would work around that.

Comment: `grep .` would remove the empty lines (`mkdir $'/var/kafka/a\n\n\nb'`) or lines without valid characters (`mkdir $'/var/kafka/a\n\x80\x81\x82\nb'`). `grep '^'` would be better.

Comment: Beware that depending on the locale and system, `[0-9]` could match more than 0123456789. Again `LC_ALL=C` would address that.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thank you for your advice! I've incorporated your suggestions. There are just sooooo many footguns/edge cases I don't even know about, thank you very much for inputting your experience :)

Comment: But now I'm really curious - How could `[0-9]` match something other than digits? What kind of (to me insane) locale would that be?

Answer (score 0):

Another variant:

```
[ -z "$(LC_ALL=C find /var/kafka -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \( -name '*[0-9]' -o -print -quit \))" ]
```

This returns true (`$?` is 0) if all directory names end in a digit